# Reading All contents of a text document line by line

Tags: c#

I have a text document with multiple lines which contain a persons name, age, favourite number and their favourite activity.

For example:

```
Line 1: Josh 30 100 Likes to play soccer. 
Line 2: May 21 3 Likes to dance.
etc.
```

I have a message box which I would like to show their name, age, favourite number and activity one by one.

How can I do this and how can I pick up their number as integers too? thanks.

Sorry I have no code as I don't know what to do but I was thinking of using streamreader.

Comment: A start: `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")`

Comment: Use search engine. I.e. bing [c# Reading All contents of a text document line by line](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+Reading+All+contents+of+a+text+document+line+by+line) give you very good MSDN [walkthrough for reading file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx)...

Answer (score 5):

Here are the tools you need for your task:

For **reading the lines** of the file (Blorgbeard's suggestion):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
```

For **getting the values of each line** (assuming that the names can be one-word only):

```
string[] values = line.Split(new char[]{' '},4);
```

For **converting a value from `String` to `Integer`**:

```
int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(strValue);
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Can you give me some more example codes